# Custom Knockout subscribable function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I created a custom subscribable function that formats phone number to an xxx-xxx-xxxx format and it works really well. However, a new constraint must be added so that if a user types in a value that has more than 11 digits then it should not format the number. Can you tell me why this code is still formatting input of more than 11 digits?

```
ko.subscribable.fn.formatPhoneNumber = function () {
        return ko.computed({
            read: function () {
                if (this().length > 11) {
                    return this();
                } else {
                    return this()
                        .replace(/\D+/g, "")
                        .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                        .substring(0, 12);
                }
            },
            write: function (value) {
                if (this(value).length > 11) {
                    this(value);
                    this.valueHasMutated();
                } else {
                    this(value.replace(/\D+/g, "")
                        .replace(/^[01]/, "")
                        .replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3")
                        .substring(0, 12));
                    this.valueHasMutated();
                }
            },
            owner: this
        }).extend({ notify: 'always' });
    };
```

Comment: My thought is that Format Phone number doesn't seem to be generic enough to be added to the `subscribable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a logical error here:

```
if (this(value).length > 11) { ...
```

IMO should be:

```
if (value.length > 11) { ...
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!